# Cannot kotlinc-native compile restful service with Spring

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-native

Quick Question: Is it possible to convert a Kotlin + Spring restful web service to a linux native application?

It works properly when run on the JVM, but I get compilation errors when I try to build it using kotlinc-native for linux.

I cannot find any definitive statement about whether I am trying to do something that is unsupported.  Am I trying to swim upstream, here?

Thank you for your comments and help!
Mike

Here are some details...
Ubuntu 18.04
Latest versions of stable dependencies

[image: The Simple Code]

[image: The Compilation Errors]

Comment: Do you have a native library for JSTL, ServletAPI, etc.? These things are provided by your app container (jetty, tomcat etc.) and are not compiled into your application. If your kotlin-native wrapper doesn't provide those, you wouldn't have any success, even if you did resolve your compile errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not link a jvm library with kotlin-native. You must have a C library to be able to link it or convert the java code to kotlin.

If what you need is a embedded server executable you could check the [ktor project](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor).

The project have some client native examples and a embedded native [http2-push](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/master/feature/http2-push).